# How can I create a custom command to fill fields in both scenarios with different structures?

Tags: css-selectors, cypress

So I have 2 scenarios, from different pages on the application I'm testing:

**Scenario 1:**

```js
<tbody>   
     <tr>
        <td class="colLabel90 colCampo">
          <label style="font-weight: bold">* Nome:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input  type="text" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all requiredColor role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
        </td>   
     </tr>
     <tr>
         .....   
     </tr> 
</tbody>
```

**Scenario 2:**

```js
<tr role="row">
   <th id="dataTableFormId:DataTableId:j_idt169" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-column ui-filter-column ui-resizable-column colFilterSize" role="columnheader" aria-label="Nome: activate to sort column ascending" scope="col" style="width:90%" aria-sort="other">
      <span class="ui-column-resizer ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="ui-column-title">Name</span>
      <span class="ui-sortable-column-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"> </span>
      <input id="dataTableFormId:DataTableId:j_idt169:filter" name="dataTableFormId:DataTableId:j_idt169:filter" class="ui-column-filter ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
   </th>
   <th id="dataTableFormId:DataTableId:j_idt171" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-column ui-filter-column ui-resizable-column colFilterSize" role="columnheader" aria-label="Fabricante: activate to sort column ascending" scope="col" style="width:90%">
      <span class="ui-column-resizer ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="ui-column-title">Manufacturer</span>
      <span class="ui-sortable-column-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
      <input id="dataTableFormId:DataTableId:j_idt171:filter" name="dataTableFormId:DataTableId:j_idt171:filter" class="ui-column-filter ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
   </th>
</tr>
```

Here is what I'm trying to do on Cypress:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("typeOnFields", (field, value) => {
   cy.get('#center').contains(field).parent().find('input').clear().type(value)

})
//Where field is the name of the field in <label> or <span>, in this case it's 'Name'
```

This is not working, find() won't find the input in any scenario.

Comment: I don't see an element with `id="center"`. If that's true, then Cypress can't find your `cy.get()` and obviously can't get the rest. Also, what happens if you switch out `.parent().find('input')` to `siblings('input')`? Can you also post the exact error message you receive?

Comment: @agoff, I didn't add the element #center because it was not necessary, but it gets the whole page and it's working.
I changed find() for siblings('input') and here's the result: 

Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find element: input, but never found it. Queried from element: <th#dataTableFormId:DataTableId:j_idt169.ui-state-default.ui-sortable-column.ui-filter-column.ui-resizable-column.colFilterSize>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the two scenarios have different structures and parent elements, you would need to use a variant of `.parents()` that keeps moving up to the first parent that contains an input

```js
cy.contains(field)             // return the <label> or <span> with "field"
  .parents(':has(input)')      // move up until element has an <input> inside
  .eq(0)                       // take first (multiple are returned)
  .find('input')               // find the <input> element   
  .clear().type(value)
```

To avoid complexity, I would actually use two commands here one for the table header and one for the table body.